# Why if I return primitive long type class in getColumnClass sorting in jtable doesn't work?

Tags: java, reflection, long-integer, primitive-types

I have a problem with sorting primitive long in JTable. I have a class, this class extends AbstractTableModel and overrides method getColumnClass, here is the code of this method:

```
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return columnFields[columnIndex].getType();
}
```

So, this method uses reflection api for getting class type. And I notice, that, if I change in my class(which stored in this tablemodel) type from long on Long, sorting will work correct. But if I use long instead Long, jtable interpreters this value as a string and sorting it as a string.
Notice: columnFields is array of fields of the stored class.
What is this? How to fix it? How to make this working for any type long or Long?

Comment: A column type *cannot* be a primitive afaik

Comment: Shouldn't use a primitive type in this case?

Comment: Does the [`getValueAt` method of your `TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getValueAt(int,int)) return a `long` or a `Long`? Obviously the latter, as the method’s return type is `Object`. Hence, the correct column type is `Long`.